# Splint - Parse errors due to compiler-specific keywords -__attribute__((weak))

Tags: c++, c, static-analysis, parse-error, splint

Currently i'm having parse errors, due to compiler specific keywords and i can't figure out how to solve them.

Here is example: keyword **`__attribute__`** have the parameter in double brackers **`((weak))`**. I've tried -D trick to ignore the keyword, but it doesn't work since Splint is complaining about brackets.

```
void __attribute__((weak)) AES_RoundKeysCreate128(void *roundKeysStruct, void *baseKey);
```

I've tried to isolate the keyword with **`#ifndef S_SPLINS_S`** and it worked, but i have so many keywords in files that i might get old when editing.

Error message from Splint:

```
Parse Error. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors).
```

Is there any more elegant way to do so ?

And one more thing.

I'm struggling to find command which will disable warnings reported from inside the Standard C libraries like (stdio.h, math.h,...).
I want to disable them since there is nothing i can do about it.

Thank you for support !!

Comment: Please add the full and exact error messages to your question

Comment: Splint hasn't had a release in over a decade. There are modern, better tools available like clang-tidy.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I've added error message to question. Not very useful message. But the problem is in __Attribute__((weak)) keyword as in non C-standard one. Thank you for suggestion Shawn. I'll give it a look, but i've went into Splint as many stated that is a good tool. But still Splint may be obsolete....

Comment: And i would prefer tools that run on windows...If there are no, than Linux tools...